# I have a complete ruby project on my system but how do I run it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a complete ruby project on my system that I downloaded from github.com and I want to run it on my Windows machine.

I have already installed Ruby and Rails on my system, but I have no idea how to run this project. The directory of this project is something like:

```
C:\Users\{username}\Desktop\BitcoinFundi\BitcoinFundi
```

How would I run this project on my system?

Comment: this is my first experience in rub on rails

Comment: Please read "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)". How to do this is part of any Rails tutorial, of which there are probably hundreds out there.

Answer (score 0):

To run your Ruby on Rails application, use the following command:

```
rails server
```

This will start the server and you will be able to access the application in your browser at `http://localhost:3000`. Port 3000 is default and you can change it in the application settings.

To run a Ruby script use:

```
ruby name_of_script.rb
```

Comment: mysql client is missing. Check your installation of MySQL or Connector/C, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out various resources and tutorials on getting started with rails.

As you say in your comment this is your first experience with Ruby on Rails, I think you should follow through chapter 1 and 2 (at least) of [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning). After that you should have a better understanding of how you start up a rails app and configure the DB. You also need a bunch of other libraries and software such as mysql from the sounds of it.

You should also read [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).  Section 4 covers how to start the default rails server.

Here is a guide on [setting up a Rails environment for Windows](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10), which is one of many guides, that shows you some of the needed steps to get a fully working environment.